# How can I reuse ansible roles I have written?

Tags: ansible

Lets say I have numerous ansible playbooks for various personal projects. They all do wildly different things, but they have a few repeated roles in common.

For example one of the roles clones my personal dot-files repository so I can have my personal `.bash_profile`, `.vimrc`, etc... on every server.

All my playbooks are in separate git repositories. Right now each of them duplicates the "dotfiles" role separately.

Is there a good way I can move that re-usable role to a separate repository and have each of the invidiual playbooks import that as needed?

Answer (score 6):

## Prerequisite

Have each role in its own git repository.

## Typical project structure

This can be challenged. that's the one I like to use on different of my projects:

```
├── inventories
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── group_vars/
│   │   └── hosts.ini
│   └── prod
│       ├── group_vars/
│       └── hosts.ini
├── group_vars/
├── host_vars/
├── files/
├── templates/
├── roles
│   ├── localy_versionned_role1/
│   ├── localy_versionned_role2/
│   ├── requirements.yml
│   ├── .gitignore
├── ansible.cfg
├── README.md
├── some_playbook.yml
├── other_playbook.yml
```

## roles/.gitignore

```
# Ignore everything in dir...
/*

# ... but current file...
!.gitignore

# ... external role requirement file
!requirements.yml

# ... and configured custom/local roles
!localy_versionned_role*/
```

## roles/requirements.yml

```
# Classic galaxy role
- src: galaxy_user.role_name

# Git available role
- src: git@git.service.com:path/to/repo.git
  scm: git
  version: master
  name: local_role_name
```

You only need to list "top" roles, dependencies (listed in `meta/main.yml` of the role) will be downloaded also.

## Ansible.cfg

We make sure that roles are searched and downloaded in our local folder

```
roles_path = roles
```

## Workflow to deploy from your project:

- Clone your project repository
- Download the external roles:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r roles/requirements
```

- Launch your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/dev some_playbook.yml
```

## Going further

### Downloading the roles as git workspaces

By default, ansible-galaxy downloads from git and removes the local repository structure (i.e. the `.git` directory). If you want to download the roles and keep working on them (change, commit, push...), you can keep the git structure with:

```
ansible-galaxy install -g -r roles/requirements
```

Note that this will write a `meta/.galaxy_install_info` file inside your role that git will see as new if you did not ignore already.

### Updating roles after first install

Roles will not be updated with a new version (especially from galaxy) if they are already installed. To force updating use:

```
ansible-galaxy -f -r roles/requirements.yml
```

of course you do this also to switch to git workspace version (or reset to version given in requirements file)

```
ansible-galaxy -f -g -r roles/requirements.yml
```

Comment: Ah so it seems `ansible-galaxy` is the tool that manages all this. Had no idea, thank you!